# browser parameter FilterConfig?=null

Tags: jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

why am I getting null for parameter value  when I type the following in the url address ?
http://192.168.0.38:8080/demo-rest//SimpleServlet?example-param=freddie

21-02-14 19:39:56:567  INFO default task-1 stdout:71 - Test Param null

21-02-14 19:39:56:568  INFO default task-1 example.SimpleHttpServlet:29 - SimpleServlet::constructor
21-02-14 19:39:56:568  INFO default task-1 example.SimpleHttpServlet:34 - SimpleServlet::init()
21-02-14 19:39:56:569  INFO default task-1 stdout:71 - IP 192.168.0.38 Time is Sun Feb 14 19:39:56 GMT 2021
21-02-14 19:39:56:569  INFO default task-1 example.SimpleHttpServlet:47 - SimpleServlet::doGet

@WebFilter("/*")
public class LoggingFilter implements Filter {

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    // Log the IP address and get the current time stamp.       
    String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
    System.out.println("IP "+ ipAddress + " Time is " + new Date().toString());
    chain.doFilter(request, response);      
}

public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    
    // Get init Parameter
    String testParam = config.getInitParameter("example-param");
    // print the init Parameter
    System.out.println("Test Param " + testParam);              
}

public void Destroy() {
    // release any resource
}
```

}

Comment: even now with inserting the following in the web.xml still getting null value. <filter>
    <filter-name>loggingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.example.LoggingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>example-param</param-name>
      <param-value>Freddy</param-value>
    </init-param>   
 </filter>
 
 <filter-mapping>
 <filter-name>loggingFilter</filter-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>

Comment: I have sorted it but I wonder if it can be done without using the web.xml 00:18:38,639 21-02-15 00:18:53:800  INFO default task-1 example.LoggingFilter:29 - Test Param Freddy

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted it but I wonder if it can be done without using the web.xml 00:18:38,639 21-02-15 00:18:53:800 INFO default task-1 example.LoggingFilter:29 - Test Param Freddy – RocknRolla 12 secs ago   Edit   Delete

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that if you use web.xml to store init-param then an object of the concrete class  of interface javax.servlet.Filter is called twice .Your code will run twice , picking the init-param value once and null the second time.  But if you uses annotations for the webinitparams then the object methods are only called once as they should be. Strange but true.!

@WebFilter(filterName = "filterSimpleServlet",
urlPatterns ={"/SimpleServlet"},
initParams =
{@WebInitParam(name = "mood", value = "awake")})